# Can't connect to iot.west.amazonaws.com

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, iot, aws-cli

I am trying to setup an IoT AWS on my raspberry pi and when I try and describe my certificate it says it couldn't reach the endpoint URL iot.west.amazonaws.com. I can ping amazonaws.com which is the actual domain. I've tried changing my DNS to Google's public one (8.8.8.8) but still no luck. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that's a valid address?

The format is usually service.region.amazonaws.com. "west" isn't a region.

Try: https://iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 1):

The official [AWS Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) for AWS IoT are:

```
Region          Endpoint
us-east-2       iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
us-east-1       iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
us-west-2       iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
ap-southeast-1  iot.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
ap-southeast-2  iot.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
ap-northeast-1  iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
ap-northeast-2  iot.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com
eu-central-1    iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
eu-west-1       iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
eu-west-2       iot.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
cn-north-1      iot.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com
```